# Is there a way to specify a manual approval stage within the buildspec.yml for AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know that within CodePipeline I can add a manual approval stage (which I can use to publish  an sns topic/get an approval from someone) - is it possible to codify this within the buildspec.yml alone? As it stands my buildspec.yml looks like this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
    commands:
      - ASSUME_ROLE_ARN="arn:aws:iam::accountnum:role/ServerlessAssumeRole"
      - TEMP_ROLE=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn $ASSUME_ROLE_ARN --role-session-name codebuild)
      - export TEMP_ROLE
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')

      - npm install -g serverless
      - npm install
      - npx tsc
  build:
    commands:
      - sls deploy --stage dev --region eu-west-2 --verbose
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo build complete
```

is there a step I can add within the "pre-build" phase which pauses the build, creates a manual approval stage and publishes it to sns before continuing the build?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, individual CodeBuild actions cannot have a manual approval process inside of them. The manual approval process is a different type of pipeline action. You would need to place the manual approval action in the pipeline before the CodeBuild action.